# VideoView in a live wallpaper?

Tags: android, android-videoview, live-wallpaper

As per other questions [android-video-as-a-live-wallpaper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825913/android-video-as-a-live-wallpaper), is the only way to play a video in a live wallpaper is to decode it yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Just use MediaPlayer instead of VideoView and use MediaPlayer.setSurface instead of MediaPlayer.setDisplay. If you use setDisplay the MediaPlayer trys to tell the SurfaceHolder to keep the screen on which isn't allowed for LiveWallpapers and will throw an error.

I use WebM/vpx8 video but this should work with whatever MediaPlayer supports (just put the video file in res/raw)

```
package com.justinbuser.nativecore;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import com.justinbuser.android.Log;

public class VideoWallpaperService extends WallpaperService
    {
        protected static int                playheadTime = 0;

        @Override
        public Engine onCreateEngine()
            {
                return new VideoEngine();
            }

        class VideoEngine extends Engine
            {

                private final String        TAG     = getClass().getSimpleName();
                private final MediaPlayer   mediaPlayer;
                public VideoEngine()
                    {
                        super();
                        Log.i( TAG, "( VideoEngine )");
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.wallpapervideo);
                        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    }

                @Override
                public void onSurfaceCreated( SurfaceHolder holder )
                    {
                        Log.i( TAG, "onSurfaceCreated" );
                        mediaPlayer.setSurface(holder.getSurface());
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }

                @Override
                public void onSurfaceDestroyed( SurfaceHolder holder )
                    {
                        Log.i( TAG, "( INativeWallpaperEngine ): onSurfaceDestroyed" );
                        playheadTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                    }
        }

}
```

Comment: How do I set the scale of the video to various methods? 
I want to put it and view it in various scaling methods, but for now I've found out only how to do it with the normal MediaPlayer, and it scales it by stretching, which isn't nice:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/50091878/878126

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes. Long answer is http://ikaruga2.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/video-live-wallpaper-part-1/

Comment: thank you, I was aware and I have built accordingly the ikaruga2 tutorial. The point is that tutorial, which is very very good actually, leaves some problems open, one of them is the Audio... LISA

Comment: you also need audio? That is quite a challenge. Read the documentation(it is a bit shaky in audio I know) and you might get an idea. 

You have to think that, for example, audio might be used by other resources too and that is quite a complex task to manage it. Good luck and I hope you succeed.

P.S. I guess you know that this is going to be extremely battery intensive app, right?

Comment: yes it's a challenge... that is why I am looking for an alternative approach. Thanks anyway! LISA

Comment: Is that your blog? @MayTheSchwartzBeWithYou

Answer (score 0):

Just to think outside the box, is it possible to take a working video player and re-parent it under a java window in Android?  I have not done this in Linux or Android, but under Windows it is possible to get the window handle of a running application and make it a child of a Java frame, with the result that the other application's window looks like its part of your Java application.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the Justin Buser solution and it does not work (tested on a API 16 device), have also found a similar code on https://github.com/thorikawa/AndroidExample/tree/master/MovieLiveWallpaper/; it does not work either. 
The only solution seems to be to use FFMPEG with NDK. eg : https://github.com/frankandrobot