# How to fit video in Live wallpaper, by center-crop and by fitting to width/height?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, live-wallpaper

### Background

I'm making a live wallpaper that can show a video. In the beginning I thought this is going to be very hard, so some people suggested using OpenGL solutions or other, very complex solutions (such as [**this one**](https://github.com/frankandrobot/FFvideoLiveWallpaper)).

Anyway, for this, I've found various places talking about it, and based on this [**github library**](https://github.com/thorikawa/AndroidExample) (which has some bugs), I finally got it to work.

### The problem

While I've succeeded showing a video, I can't find the way to control how it's shown compared to the screen resolution.

Currently it always gets to be stretched to the screen size, meaning that this (video taken from [**here**](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4)) :

[image]

gets to show as this:

[image]

Reason is the different aspect ratio : 560x320 (video resolution) vs 1080x1920 (device resolution).

Note: I'm well aware of solutions of scaling videos, that are available on various Github repositories (such as [**here**](https://github.com/yqritc/Android-ScalableVideoView)), but I'm asking about a live wallpaper. As such, it doesn't have a View, so it's more limited about how to do things. To be more specifically, a solution can't have any kind of layout, a TextureView or a SurfaceView, or any other kind of View.

### What I've tried

I tried to play with various fields and functions of the SurfaceHolder, but with no luck so far. Examples:

- **[setVideoScalingMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVideoScalingMode(int))** - it either crashes or doesn't do anything.
- changing [**surfaceFrame**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#getSurfaceFrame()) - same.

Here's the current code I've made (full project available [**here**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MovieLiveWallpaper)) :

```
class MovieLiveWallpaperService : WallpaperService() {
    override fun onCreateEngine(): WallpaperService.Engine {
        return VideoLiveWallpaperEngine()
    }

    private enum class PlayerState {
        NONE, PREPARING, READY, PLAYING
    }

    inner class VideoLiveWallpaperEngine : WallpaperService.Engine() {
        private var mp: MediaPlayer? = null
        private var playerState: PlayerState = PlayerState.NONE

        override fun onSurfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
            super.onSurfaceCreated(holder)
            Log.d("AppLog", "onSurfaceCreated")
            mp = MediaPlayer()
            val mySurfaceHolder = MySurfaceHolder(holder)
            mp!!.setDisplay(mySurfaceHolder)
            mp!!.isLooping = true
            mp!!.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f)
            mp!!.setOnPreparedListener { mp ->
                playerState = PlayerState.READY
                setPlay(true)
            }
            try {
                //mp!!.setDataSource(this@MovieLiveWallpaperService, Uri.parse("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"))
                mp!!.setDataSource(this@MovieLiveWallpaperService, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.small))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }
        }

        override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            Log.d("AppLog", "onDestroy")
            if (mp == null)
                return
            mp!!.stop()
            mp!!.release()
            playerState = PlayerState.NONE
        }

        private fun setPlay(play: Boolean) {
            if (mp == null)
                return
            if (play == mp!!.isPlaying)
                return
            when {
                !play -> {
                    mp!!.pause()
                    playerState = PlayerState.READY
                }
                mp!!.isPlaying -> return
                playerState == PlayerState.READY -> {
                    Log.d("AppLog", "ready, so starting to play")
                    mp!!.start()
                    playerState = PlayerState.PLAYING
                }
                playerState == PlayerState.NONE -> {
                    Log.d("AppLog", "not ready, so preparing")
                    mp!!.prepareAsync()
                    playerState = PlayerState.PREPARING
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onVisibilityChanged(visible: Boolean) {
            super.onVisibilityChanged(visible)
            Log.d("AppLog", "onVisibilityChanged:" + visible + " " + playerState)
            if (mp == null)
                return
            setPlay(visible)
        }

    }

    class MySurfaceHolder(private val surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder) : SurfaceHolder {
        override fun addCallback(callback: SurfaceHolder.Callback) = surfaceHolder.addCallback(callback)

        override fun getSurface() = surfaceHolder.surface!!

        override fun getSurfaceFrame() = surfaceHolder.surfaceFrame

        override fun isCreating(): Boolean = surfaceHolder.isCreating

        override fun lockCanvas(): Canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas()

        override fun lockCanvas(dirty: Rect): Canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(dirty)

        override fun removeCallback(callback: SurfaceHolder.Callback) = surfaceHolder.removeCallback(callback)

        override fun setFixedSize(width: Int, height: Int) = surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(width, height)

        override fun setFormat(format: Int) = surfaceHolder.setFormat(format)

        override fun setKeepScreenOn(screenOn: Boolean) {}

        override fun setSizeFromLayout() = surfaceHolder.setSizeFromLayout()

        override fun setType(type: Int) = surfaceHolder.setType(type)

        override fun unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas: Canvas) = surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
    }
}
```

### The questions

I'd like to know how to adjust the scale the content based on what we have for ImageView, all while keeping the aspect ratio  :

1. center-crop - fits to 100% of the container (the screen in this case), cropping on sides (top&bottom or left&right) when needed. Doesn't stretch anything. This means the content seems fine, but not all of it might be shown.
2. fit-center - stretch to fit width/height
3. center-inside - set as original size, centered, and stretch to fit width/height only if too large.

Comment: have you tried setting the video size to the surface holder using setFixedSize

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy For some reason it gives me `UnsupportedOperationException: Wallpapers currently only support sizing from layout` . Also, I don't know with which values to set it.

Comment: You have a video, so unless you edit the actual file, you have to set it to play inside a sized layout. I don't think that's possible with the WallpaperService. Have you tried Daydream?

Comment: @ChVas I'm talking about live wallpaper. Not Daydream. Also, it is possible. I've seen other live wallpapers do it.

Comment: @androiddeveloper have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211837/full-screen-videoview-without-stretching-the-video)

Comment: @Nainal How can I try it? All answers there are about views, using LayoutParams. The only solution without it - is using `setFixedSize`, which I've written that causes a crash.

Comment: Could you supply a link to github (or something else) to the project? The link you provided is no longer available.

Comment: @Jalvap OK updated link.

Comment: Probably a very bad idea but the only one I can think of which might actually work, is to set up a canvas, and extract frame by frame from the movie and draw it to the canvas, but that will be extremely costly. Then you will be able to manipulate the image as you need/want

Comment: I want an efficient solution. Should be smooth.

Comment: Do you have a `xml` file for that?

Comment: @AAShakil XML file for what? It's a live wallpaper. All in code.

Comment: What's the minimum API version you'd like this working on? All the way back for live wallpapers?

Comment: @TheHebrewHammer Relatively high currently (minSdkVersion 27) , but might be lower in the future. Why?

Comment: No reason yet, just wanted to have all the relevant info before I start on this on Monday. I've done a bunch of AR work with opengl, never touched live wallpapers yet, should be fun.

Comment: @TheHebrewHammer OK thank you.

Comment: I've gotten `center-crop` and `fit-center` so far... Still working on `center-inside`

Comment: @TheHebrewHammer Wow. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, a few hours later and basically what I've got is a detailed explanation of how hard it would be to do fit-top, fit-center, or fit-bottom. I'll still give it a shot later but I think for now you're basically stuck with fit-xy and center-crop. I'll post what I have so far tomorrow and will update if I find a reasonable way to get the other mode.

Comment: `MediPlayer` has [its own method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVideoScalingMode(int)) to set scaling. Did you try it with `VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING`?

Comment: @Ircover I've already written about this method on the question itself. Please re-read what I wrote. Maybe I don't use it correctly, as it crashes or doesn't do anything. Have you succeeded

Comment: @TheHebrewHammer Can you please post the solution that you've made so far? The one with both the scaling? I think center-crop is better than the fit-xy I've come up with...

Comment: That's the one I posted, there's a GitHub link for the full source.

Comment: @TheHebrewHammer For some reason each time I try to clone, it doesn't have the files that are on the website. It shows something with RecyclerView. Odd. Had to download the zip file instead. Will check it later. Have to go now. Please let's write on the answer you've written instead of here, ok?

Comment: Make sure you go to the right branch

Comment: @TheHebrewHammer Oh you've created multiple branches already... But the other seems weird. It has RecyclerView... Also, the project for some reason doesn't let me have auto-completion on the IDE. Doesn't even mark errors. And when I try center-crop, for some reason it doesn't get shown well on the preview screen (before setting it), using the ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER Intent, yet it does seem to work when I do set it.

Comment: Yeah, so I'm going to start just using one repo for all my stack overflow samples. I need to clean master so it's a blank project, branch makes are stack overflow question IDs. Internet here is very spotty but for now I didn't support any dynamic configuration, you have to compile it with CENTER_CROP as the mode.

Comment: @TheHebrewHammer I know. That's what I did. In the preview it doesn't look right, but when actually setting it, it works fine.

Comment: That's very strange, I used a pixel and Nexus 6 and both preview and final set looked good. What device and what API level are you running, I'd love to try and reproduce

Comment: @TheHebrewHammer I have Pixel 2 with Android P. Here's the modified project and images of what I see (IDE shows it differently for some reason) of the issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116250247

Comment: Ok, my wife has a pixel 2 so I'll test when I get back from vacation on that one. I'm running P on my pixel, odd that it's different.

Comment: Please let's continue this on the answer you wrote and not here. Also, did you understand what I tried to show? The preview step is different from the one on the launcher (after setting the live wallpaper). To me it looks like a bug (this and the fact that the IDE got a different way to show the content than what's on the device).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I wasn't yet able to get all scale types that you've asked but I've been able to get fit-xy and center-crop working fairly easily using exo player. The full code can be seen at https://github.com/yperess/StackOverflow/tree/50091878 and I'll update it as I get more. Eventually I'll also fill the MainActivity to allow you to choose the scaling type as the settings (I'll do this with a simple PreferenceActivity) and read the shared preferences value on the service side.

The overall idea is that deep down MediaCodec already implements both fit-xy and center-crop which are really the only 2 modes you would need if you had access to a view hierarchy. This is the case because fit-center, fit-top, fit-bottom would all really just be fit-xy where the surface has a gravity and is scaled to match the video size * minimum scaling. To get these working what I believe will need to happen is we'd need to create an OpenGL context and provide a SurfaceTexture. This SurfaceTexture can be wrapped with a stub Surface which can be passed to exo player. Once the video is loaded we can set the size of these since we created them. We also have a callback on SurfaceTexture to let us know when a frame is ready. At this point we should be able to modify the frame (hopefully just using a simple matrix scale and transform).

The key components here are creating the exo player:

```
    private fun initExoMediaPlayer(): SimpleExoPlayer {
        val videoTrackSelectionFactory = AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter)
        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory)
        val player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this@MovieLiveWallpaperService,
                trackSelector)
        player.playWhenReady = true
        player.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
        player.volume = 0f
        if (mode == Mode.CENTER_CROP) {
            player.videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING
        } else {
            player.videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT
        }
        if (mode == Mode.FIT_CENTER) {
            player.addVideoListener(this)
        }
        return player
    }
```

Then loading the video:

```
    override fun onSurfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
        super.onSurfaceCreated(holder)
        if (mode == Mode.FIT_CENTER) {
            // We need to somehow wrap the surface or set some scale factor on exo player here.
            // Most likely this will require creating a SurfaceTexture and attaching it to an
            // OpenGL context. Then for each frame, writing it to the original surface but with
            // an offset
            exoMediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(holder.surface)
        } else {
            exoMediaPlayer.setVideoSurfaceHolder(holder)
        }

        val videoUri = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.small)
        val dataSourceFactory = DataSource.Factory { RawResourceDataSource(context) }
        val mediaSourceFactory = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
        exoMediaPlayer.prepare(mediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(videoUri))
    }
```

UPDATE:

Got it working, I'll need tomorrow to clean it up before I post the code but here's a sneak preview...
[image: fit_center]

What I ended up doing it basically taking GLSurfaceView and ripping it apart. If you look at the source for it the only thing missing that's making it impossible to use in a wallpaper is the fact that it only starts the GLThread when attached to the window. So if you replicate the same code but allow to manually start the GLThread you can go ahead. After that you just need to keep track of how big your screen is vs the video after scaling to the minimum scale that would fit and shift the quad on which you draw to.

Known issues with the code:
1. There's a small bug with the GLThread I haven't been able to fish out. Seems like there's a simple timing issue where when the thread pauses I get a call to `signallAll()` that's not actually waiting on anything.
2. I didn't bother dynamically modifying the mode in the renderer. It shouldn't be too hard. Add a preference listener when creating the Engine then update the renderer when `scale_type` changes.

UPDATE:
All issues have been resolved. `signallAll()` was throwing because I missed a check to see that we actually have the lock. I also added a listener to update the scale type dynamically so now all scale types use the GlEngine.

ENJOY!

Comment: Yes, that's also what I got when I talked with them on the Github of ExoPlayer: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4457 . But how come some apps succeed showing the video scaling in other ways?

Comment: Yeah, it's all manual in open gl. I'm working on that part, just not really there yet. I'll commit when ready and update the answer

Comment: Wait, so which scaling types you got?

Comment: Currently implemented are center cropping (keeps aspect ratio and both edges are >= to screen) and fit XY (both edges == screen, loses aspect ratio), I'm still working on fit-center which will keep the aspect ratio but fill the height/width and center the video, this one should be similar enough to where I'll probably implement fit-bottom and fit-top along with it. I'm going to try and get it done but I'm heading out tomorrow morning to take my daughter hiking for 5 days so we'll see if I finish on time. Regardless, I'm gonna figure this out :)

Comment: But fixXY is the one I got, which is almost never really used... How will you do the fit-center?

Comment: What I'm working on right now is creating a SurfaceTexture and having exoplayer write to that. On each frame I should be able to copy the frame buffer in opengl. I "should" be able then to write that buffer to the wallpaper's surface after applying scaling and transformations. In theory all the pieces should work... Theory is nice though. I'll post after I've finished trying it.

Comment: This seems like a good plan, but will it be the same in terms of efficiency? I don't want it to consume battery too much...

Comment: I'll run the profiler and let you know. All of this will run on the GPU directly so I think it'll be fine.

Comment: OK try to compare between your original solution and the new one .

Comment: Check out the screenshot! I'll push the full source tomorrow when it's a bit cleaner.

Comment: Good news. I'm very happy. Please let me know when you got it well.

Comment: Updated and pushed to the branch

Comment: Wait, so you got all 3 types of scaling? And all work well? I've tested the sample, but it doesn't seem to change when I change the scale type. And if I do it from the live-wallpaper preview screen (press the settings icon there, to go to the app's settings), it turns black when I go back to see the changes.

Comment: Check out the known bugs, after you change the settings, go back twice out of the preview then open again. It was very late and I don't have the energy to dynamically update so you need to create a new engine

Comment: I see. OK. I will now accept the answer. If you solve all the issues, I will put a new bounty and grant it.

Comment: Issues resolved and pushed. Give it a try and let me know if it works on your end.

Comment: I think you still have an issue there. I tried to switch between each of the scaling types. When I reached fit-end, and switched to fit-xy, it went black.

Comment: I submitted a pull request to address the incorrect scaling applied for center-crop. There was an issue with the scale being truncated to whole integer numbers, where floating point precision is required. I'm still trying to figure out why the rendering stops randomly.

Comment: I have also submitted an issue to the git repo, which contains more information about the 'black screen' issue.

Comment: I have resolved the black screen bug, and confirmed the issue (that ExoPlayer was writing to a Surface which had been destroyed). I will detail my approach on the GitHub repo in an issue. I changed the architecture significantly, and I think that this will need more discussion than is practical here.

Comment: Which scale-types did you implement eventually? Do they also include scrolling if you wanted ? And did you succeed to fix all issues it had?

Comment: I don't recall that I got all the different scales figured out on that project. If I have time I'll try to test and update, but things have been crazy lately and time is of low supply :)

I'll gladly accept pull requests though.

Comment: A lot of the code now is deprecated, and even if I try to fix all deprecated issues, it will either crash or not show anything. Can you please update it?

Comment: guys any update on this issue. Can @androiddeveloper share the source code if it's open (the code which you guys are talking abt)

Comment: @FusionDevelopers I wrote just above you that I tried to use what he did, but a lot got deprecated and I had issues with it... :(

Comment: Sad. I'm trying to add a feature in your fork of alynx live wp. The feature is to animate/play the video when screen is unlocked. 99% it's done but sometimes when the playback is over (State ended) and we lock & unlock the screen video jumps from the end scene (last frame) to first frame. Could you try to help me on this?

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this with a TextureView. (surfaceView won't work either).I have found some code which will help you for achieving this.
in this demo you can crop the video in three type **center, top & bottom**.

**TextureVideoView.java**

```
public class TextureVideoView extends TextureView implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

    // Indicate if logging is on
    public static final boolean LOG_ON = true;

    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = TextureVideoView.class.getName();

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    private float mVideoHeight;
    private float mVideoWidth;

    private boolean mIsDataSourceSet;
    private boolean mIsViewAvailable;
    private boolean mIsVideoPrepared;
    private boolean mIsPlayCalled;

    private ScaleType mScaleType;
    private State mState;

    public enum ScaleType {
        CENTER_CROP, TOP, BOTTOM
    }

    public enum State {
        UNINITIALIZED, PLAY, STOP, PAUSE, END
    }

    public TextureVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    public TextureVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    public TextureVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        initPlayer();
        setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    }

    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        mScaleType = scaleType;
    }

    private void updateTextureViewSize() {
        float viewWidth = getWidth();
        float viewHeight = getHeight();

        float scaleX = 1.0f;
        float scaleY = 1.0f;

        if (mVideoWidth > viewWidth && mVideoHeight > viewHeight) {
            scaleX = mVideoWidth / viewWidth;
            scaleY = mVideoHeight / viewHeight;
        } else if (mVideoWidth < viewWidth && mVideoHeight < viewHeight) {
            scaleY = viewWidth / mVideoWidth;
            scaleX = viewHeight / mVideoHeight;
        } else if (viewWidth > mVideoWidth) {
            scaleY = (viewWidth / mVideoWidth) / (viewHeight / mVideoHeight);
        } else if (viewHeight > mVideoHeight) {
            scaleX = (viewHeight / mVideoHeight) / (viewWidth / mVideoWidth);
        }

        // Calculate pivot points, in our case crop from center
        int pivotPointX;
        int pivotPointY;

        switch (mScaleType) {
            case TOP:
                pivotPointX = 0;
                pivotPointY = 0;
                break;
            case BOTTOM:
                pivotPointX = (int) (viewWidth);
                pivotPointY = (int) (viewHeight);
                break;
            case CENTER_CROP:
                pivotPointX = (int) (viewWidth / 2);
                pivotPointY = (int) (viewHeight / 2);
                break;
            default:
                pivotPointX = (int) (viewWidth / 2);
                pivotPointY = (int) (viewHeight / 2);
                break;
        }

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, pivotPointX, pivotPointY);

        setTransform(matrix);
    }

    private void initPlayer() {
        if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        } else {
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
        }
        mIsVideoPrepared = false;
        mIsPlayCalled = false;
        mState = State.UNINITIALIZED;
    }

    /**
     * @see MediaPlayer#setDataSource(String)
     */
    public void setDataSource(String path) {
        initPlayer();

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mIsDataSourceSet = true;
            prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see MediaPlayer#setDataSource(Context, Uri)
     */
    public void setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri) {
        initPlayer();

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
            mIsDataSourceSet = true;
            prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see MediaPlayer#setDataSource(java.io.FileDescriptor)
     */
    public void setDataSource(AssetFileDescriptor afd) {
        initPlayer();

        try {
            long startOffset = afd.getStartOffset();
            long length = afd.getLength();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), startOffset, length);
            mIsDataSourceSet = true;
            prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void prepare() {
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(
                    new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                            mVideoWidth = width;
                            mVideoHeight = height;
                            updateTextureViewSize();
                        }
                    }
            );
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mState = State.END;
                    log("Video has ended.");

                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onVideoEnd();
                    }
                }
            });

            // don't forget to call MediaPlayer.prepareAsync() method when you use constructor for
            // creating MediaPlayer
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            // Play video when the media source is ready for playback.
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mIsVideoPrepared = true;
                    if (mIsPlayCalled && mIsViewAvailable) {
                        log("Player is prepared and play() was called.");
                        play();
                    }

                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onVideoPrepared();
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Play or resume video. Video will be played as soon as view is available and media player is
     * prepared.
     *
     * If video is stopped or ended and play() method was called, video will start over.
     */
    public void play() {
        if (!mIsDataSourceSet) {
            log("play() was called but data source was not set.");
            return;
        }

        mIsPlayCalled = true;

        if (!mIsVideoPrepared) {
            log("play() was called but video is not prepared yet, waiting.");
            return;
        }

        if (!mIsViewAvailable) {
            log("play() was called but view is not available yet, waiting.");
            return;
        }

        if (mState == State.PLAY) {
            log("play() was called but video is already playing.");
            return;
        }

        if (mState == State.PAUSE) {
            log("play() was called but video is paused, resuming.");
            mState = State.PLAY;
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            return;
        }

        if (mState == State.END || mState == State.STOP) {
            log("play() was called but video already ended, starting over.");
            mState = State.PLAY;
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            return;
        }

        mState = State.PLAY;
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

    /**
     * Pause video. If video is already paused, stopped or ended nothing will happen.
     */
    public void pause() {
        if (mState == State.PAUSE) {
            log("pause() was called but video already paused.");
            return;
        }

        if (mState == State.STOP) {
            log("pause() was called but video already stopped.");
            return;
        }

        if (mState == State.END) {
            log("pause() was called but video already ended.");
            return;
        }

        mState = State.PAUSE;
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop video (pause and seek to beginning). If video is already stopped or ended nothing will
     * happen.
     */
    public void stop() {
        if (mState == State.STOP) {
            log("stop() was called but video already stopped.");
            return;
        }

        if (mState == State.END) {
            log("stop() was called but video already ended.");
            return;
        }

        mState = State.STOP;
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see MediaPlayer#setLooping(boolean)
     */
    public void setLooping(boolean looping) {
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(looping);
    }

    /**
     * @see MediaPlayer#seekTo(int)
     */
    public void seekTo(int milliseconds) {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(milliseconds);
    }

    /**
     * @see MediaPlayer#getDuration()
     */
    public int getDuration() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    static void log(String message) {
        if (LOG_ON) {
            Log.d(TAG, message);
        }
    }

    private MediaPlayerListener mListener;

    /**
     * Listener trigger 'onVideoPrepared' and `onVideoEnd` events
     */
    public void setListener(MediaPlayerListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface MediaPlayerListener {

        public void onVideoPrepared();

        public void onVideoEnd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
        Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
        mIsViewAvailable = true;
        if (mIsDataSourceSet && mIsPlayCalled && mIsVideoPrepared) {
            log("View is available and play() was called.");
            play();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

    }
}
```

After that use this class like the below code in **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

    // Video file url
    private static final String FILE_URL = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
    private TextureVideoView mTextureVideoView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initView();
        initActionBar();

        if (!isWIFIOn(getBaseContext())) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You need internet connection to stream video",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void initActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.action_list,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, this);
    }

    private void initView() {
        mTextureVideoView = (TextureVideoView) findViewById(R.id.cropTextureView);

        findViewById(R.id.btnPlay).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btnPause).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btnStop).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnPlay:
                mTextureVideoView.play();
                break;
            case R.id.btnPause:
                mTextureVideoView.pause();
                break;
            case R.id.btnStop:
                mTextureVideoView.stop();
                break;
        }
    }

    final int indexCropCenter = 0;
    final int indexCropTop = 1;
    final int indexCropBottom = 2;

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        switch (itemPosition) {
            case indexCropCenter:
                mTextureVideoView.stop();
                mTextureVideoView.setScaleType(TextureVideoView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                mTextureVideoView.setDataSource(FILE_URL);
                mTextureVideoView.play();
                break;
            case indexCropTop:
                mTextureVideoView.stop();
                mTextureVideoView.setScaleType(TextureVideoView.ScaleType.TOP);
                mTextureVideoView.setDataSource(FILE_URL);
                mTextureVideoView.play();
                break;
            case indexCropBottom:
                mTextureVideoView.stop();
                mTextureVideoView.setScaleType(TextureVideoView.ScaleType.BOTTOM);
                mTextureVideoView.setDataSource(FILE_URL);
                mTextureVideoView.play();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isWIFIOn(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }
}
```

and layout **activity_main.xml** file for that is below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.example.videocropdemo.crop.TextureVideoView
        android:id="@+id/cropTextureView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pause" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stop" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output** of the code for center crop look like

[image]

Comment: This is nice, but I've specifically written in both the title and the description, that I'm interested in how to do it for live wallpaper. It doesn't have any view in it. It doesn't even have a layout file.

Answer (score 1):

I find this article: [How to set video as live wallpaper and keep video aspect ratio(width and height)](https://medium.com/@rorocotech/how-to-set-video-as-live-wallpaper-and-keep-video-aspect-ratio-width-and-height-f4599c7b0619)

above article has simple source, just click "set wallpaper" button, if you wanna full feature app, see https://github.com/AlynxZhou/alynx-live-wallpaper

the keypoint is use glsurfaceview instead of wallpaperservice default surfaceview, make custom glsurfaceview renderer, glsurfaceview can use opengl to display, so the question become "how to use glsurfaceview play video" or **"how to use opengl play video"**

how to use glsurfaceview instead of wallpaperservice default surfaceview:

```
public class GLWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {
...

    class GLWallpaperEngine extends Engine {
...

        private class GLWallpaperSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            private static final String TAG = "GLWallpaperSurface";

            public GLWallpaperSurfaceView(Context context) {
                super(context);
            }

            /**
             * This is a hack. Because Android Live Wallpaper only has a Surface.
             * So we create a GLSurfaceView, and when drawing to its Surface,
             * we replace it with WallpaperEngine's Surface.
             */
            @Override
            public SurfaceHolder getHolder() {
                return getSurfaceHolder();
            }

            void onDestroy() {
                super.onDetachedFromWindow();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please share entire code for it? I can't reach it for some reason

Comment: @androiddeveloper see https://github.com/AlynxZhou/alynx-live-wallpaper

Comment: This is nice, but it seems like much much more than what I asked about. I just asked about a specific thing. Can you at least point me to the parts I should look at? Or write a minimal app to demonstrate it and publish here ? Sorry if it sounds rude. I've granted you +1. Hope it's ok.

Comment: @androiddeveloper see this file: https://github.com/AlynxZhou/alynx-live-wallpaper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/xyz/alynx/livewallpaper/GLWallpaperService.java, it's wallpaperservice,  it use exoplayer, change exoplayer's video source to your video, and set this wallpaperservice as live wallpaper, sorry i don't know how to use opengl but I'm sure this repo work

Comment: Yes I know it work. Just was hoping for a more minimal solution. I will check it out some day. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: Sadly this sample doesn't provide various scale type options. In fact it has only center-crop, with the option of setting it to slide... Any idea how to add other scale-types to it?

Answer (score 0):

my solution is **use gif(size and fps same with video) instead of video** in live wallpaper

see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60425717/6011193, WallpaperService can best fit gif

convert video to gif in computer with ffmpeg

or in android, video can be converted to gif in android code: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16749143/6011193

Comment: GIF is considered less efficient in both performance and size. Same goes for animated WEBP

Answer (score -10):

You can use [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) for GIF and image loading and its give scaling options as you like. Based on document https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/targets.html#sizes-and-dimensions and https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling this.

**Glide v4 requires Android Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14) or higher.**

***Like :***

```
public static void loadCircularImageGlide(String imagePath, ImageView view) {
    Glide.with(view.getContext())
            .load(imagePath)
            .asGif()
            .override(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). resize does not respect aspect ratio
            .error(R.drawable.create_timeline_placeholder)
            .fitCenter() // scaling options
            .transform(new CircularTransformation(view.getContext())) // Even you can Give image tranformation too
            .into(view);
}
```

Comment: I'm already aware of this, but this time, there is no view here. It's a live wallpaper. Please show how to do it for live wallpaper. Full code please, as I've shown.

Comment: @androiddeveloper if you need full code then you need to share your code with me.

Comment: The full code was already always available from the beginning. Please check the link. It's even on Github since yesterday.

Comment: Also, the question is about a video, not GIF