# Resize and save images

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-glide

I'm using Glide 4.7.1 trying to resize and save some photos.

```
for (String path : this.paths) {
        Glide.with(this.context).asBitmap().load(path).apply(RequestOptions.fitCenterTransform()).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(1080, 1920) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                try {
                    resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, new FileOutputStream(MasterFacade.getAppDir() + "temp/" + resource.hashCode() + ".jpg"));
                    listener.onUpdate(progressMessage, processed.get());

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I just want to resize (keeping aspect ratio) to 1080x1920 (or the nearest) and then save the new bitmap to a file.

I'm sure I've permission to write
I'm sure the `path` image exists
I'm sure `MasterFacade.getAppDir() + "temp/" + resource.hashCode() + ".jpg"` is a valid dir and I've writing permisions on it

But this code is never reached!

I tried to debug and `onResourceReady` never is called...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are the values of paths and particular path ? Please share any path here

Comment: You need to check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50617561/6238866

Comment: @MayurPatel, doesn't work anymore, i cant even call `asGif()` after calling load it must be before

Comment: @quicklearner, `this.paths` is an array of files like: `/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/100_0306_20180122200616.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

I believe none of the answer really read my problem:

**I tried to debug and onResourceReady never is called...**

So I checked glide wiki and it says:

> The second critical part is the Glide builder line .with(context). The
>   issue here is actually a feature of Glide: when you pass a context,
>   for example the current app activity, Glide will automatically stop
>   the request when the requesting activity is stopped

I was calling this code above right after call `finish()` on the activity so the code was internally stopped by Glide without throwing any exception and `onResourceReady` was never called.

Answer (score 1):

Resize the image using this in Glide 4.x

```
Glide.with(getContext())
.load(imagePath)
.apply(new RequestOptions().override(600, 200))
.fitCenter() 
.into(setImage);
```

Comment: Does not work for gif image. It does not change the size of gif

Comment: the main part is not explained in the answer. simply setting it into image view while Question is about saving resized image as file.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize image with glide using `override` function.

You can get more from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50617561/6238866

**Like :**

```
public static void loadCircularImageGlide(String imagePath, ImageView view) {
    Glide.with(view.getContext())
            .load(imagePath)
            .asBitmap()
            .override(1080,1920) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). resize does not respect aspect ratio
            .error(R.drawable.create_timeline_placeholder)
            .fitCenter() // scaling options
            .transform(new CircularTransformation(view.getContext())) // Even you can Give image tranformation too
            .into(view);
}
```

Comment: doens't work for glide 4.7.1... `override(x,y)` doens't even exist anymore

Comment: @RafaelLima You have to check this documents there for existence of override methord in 4.7.1.
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems to be causing by path , In **Glide** if you want to load image from external memory , You have to use correct path

**Make Sure the path should be valid**

```
String path="file://"+"image path";

for (String path : this.paths) {
        Glide.with(this.context).asBitmap().load("file://"+path).apply(RequestOptions.fitCenterTransform()).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(1080, 1920) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                try {
                    resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, new FileOutputStream(MasterFacade.getAppDir() + "temp/" + resource.hashCode() + ".jpg"));
                    listener.onUpdate(progressMessage, processed.get());

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Would you tell how to do this for gifs. Because it does not changes the size of gif but the static images like png jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can resize image with glide.try it...

`Glide.with(getContext())
    .load(imagePath)
    .apply(new RequestOptions().override(600, 200))
    .fitCenter() 
    .into(setImage);`

Answer (score 0):

get the image as @Gautam Kumar has done but you also have to change your imageView in the XML by adding   android:adjustViewBounds="true".

`Glide.with(getContext())
.load(imagePath)
.apply(new RequestOptions().override(600, 200))
.into(setImage);`

then your XML

```
      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/image_id"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image" />
```

Comment: The question is about saving resized image as file not setting into View